# AUFS driver not loaded / found on kernel 4.* branch

Tags: drivers, kernel

I've tried upgrading my kernel from 3.19.0-22 to any of the kernel 4.* releases in Ubuntu 15.04 but upon rebooting I've found that docker doesn't work anymore.

```
Sep 19 12:37:14 sniper docker[1098]:
time="2015-09-19T12:37:14.116981936+02:00" level=error
msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver \"aufs\" failed: driver not supported"
Sep 19 12:37:14 sniper docker[1098]:
time="2015-09-19T12:37:14.117058280+02:00" level=fatal msg="Error
starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported"
```

My question is:

Am I missing something or am I supposed to do something for this to work?

Or is it something in docker that I can change so that it works again?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Kernels 4.x are not supported in Ubuntu yet.

Comment: @dlsniper which ubuntu version you are using ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've forgot to mention that, Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 what do you mean that they are not supported in Ubuntu yet? They do appear in their mainline repository, http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and the system works otherwise without a problem. Thank you.

Comment: I mean literally that these kernels are not supported. You can install them at your own risk.  Some software may malfunction with these kernels, that is normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After installing linux kernel 4.2.1 for ubuntu (from ppa) docker stopped to function properly.

To get it back working I did:

After stopping docker service,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge docker-engine
```

then I got rid of any former container and images that were still in aufs in /var/lib/docker

```
mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.old
```

then I reinstalled docker from the script docker is hosting online:

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

docker instantly worked after reinstallation

I could probably copy and paste data from the /var/lib/docker.old so as to get containers and images, but that was not worth it in my case, so I didn't even try, but you migth consider to do this if you want to retrieve former images and containers.

Answer (score 0):

I was have the same issue,and this solve the probelm 
 `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs` 
 and i suggest to use this command to install Docker 
 `curl https://get.docker.com | bash`
 if this not solve the probelm there is many soultion in this :
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14026